# BitTorrent client transmission is low efficiency

Tags: bittorrent, transmission-daemon

I settle a BitTorrent test enviroment with: opentracker + BitTornado seed + Transmission-daemon (11 servers) and with a 40G datafile. The OS is CentOS6, Transmission 2.13 (11501).

the BitTornado cost 40% CPU, but transmission daemon cost 100% CPU, and it only run on one CPU, the bandwidth cost only 200Mbps. 
As a contract, SCP command can consumer 7 times the bandwidth.

Is there any problem? Why the transmission is so low efficiency, even poor than Python(BitTornado).

---

update info

other client is hard to test, the reason I choose transmission-daemon is that I can control from one client through transmission-remote.

And I find transmission-remote does not work for some command, for example:

transmission-remote $host -t attr.dat --remove-and-delete

Comment: The Transmission client needs to do a lot of hash checking of all the pieces it downloads, that the seeding BitTornado client don't have to do.

Comment: you should evaluate multiple clients. have you tried something libtorrent-based? I think that one is more tuned for throughput. And there are tunables you may want to adjust. IO buffers, piece flushing strategy, piece size can matter. And what is "100% CPU"? a single core or multiple cores? did you at least `strace` and `perf` it to see whether it wastes time on syscalls or spends the cycles in userspace? You're in the best position to do performance analysis since you already have a test setup. Also, have you checked their issue tracker?

Comment: all servers have 4core. In one torrent task, only one CPU can involved, and the CPU will cost 100%. I guess transmission-daemon create a thread for per task.